# Using `git checkout -b` with and without a branch starting point

Tags: git

I am new to Git, I want to know the difference between two commands.

```
`git checkout -b <branch-name>`
`git checkout -b <branch-name> origin/master`
```

If I execute the first command, how does Git create the branch? Will the branch be created from local master or remote master?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you don't specify a starting point, the new branch is created from what you currently have checked out (the current `HEAD`).

[`git-checkout`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-checkout.html):

> `git checkout -b|-B <new_branch> [<start point>]`
>
> Specifying `-b` causes a new branch to be created **as if git-branch(1) were called** and then checked out.

And [`git-branch`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-branch.html):

> [...] The command’s second form creates a new branch head named `<branchname>` which points to the current `HEAD`, or `<start-point>` if given.

Comment: So in this case `git checkout -b <branch-name> origin/master`, if I did a git push, will this go to my remote origin/master ?

Comment: By default, as written in the docs I linked to, yes when the starting point is a remote branch it will be tracked.

Comment: @annonymous, you can always verify how your local tracking branches are configured WRT your remote branches by doing `git remote -v show origin`

Comment: I have been looking through the documenation to try to find out what "start point" actually means, and not found it yet. From your answer, it implies that it could be any branch anywhere?  E.g. master, develop, release, some feature branch from master etc?

Comment: @JohnLittle: you can create a branch starting on any commit you like.